# Prioritize connections over powered USB hub?

Tags: usb, usb-hub

I work in a company which manufactures scientific equipment. In my current project, I have a need to control one *DAQ (MCC USB-2637)* and one *Digital Module (MCC USB-1024LS)* through the same USB 2.0 port on my computer. To achieve this I am planning to implement a powered USB hub in the prototype, the *USB-2637* and *USB-1024LS* are inside this prototype and will be connected to the powered USB hub. Out of these two devices, I need to prioritize the connection to *USB-2637* so that if there is communication happening between my computer and *USB-2637* or vice versa, then the communication between the computer and *USB-1024LS* is put on hold. I am thinking of controlling the USB hub through C/C++ using the same software I am making to control the *USB-2637* and *USB-1024LS* devices. Is it possible to control a USB hub in such a way? If yes, can you please suggest me what to look for (a USB hub type or any technical term on which I can get started)? I tried searching for it, but except for a few vague ideas on Quora which suggested the use of *Multi Transaction Translators (Multi-TT)* for making sure connection is consistent, I was unable to find anything else. Thanks for trying to help me :)

Answer (score 1):

That's not how USB works, even remotely. What you want isn't possible. It's the host that *asks* the devices for data, very periodically. So, either you can simply use your host to tell the device that it shouldn't be preparing data for getting polled from the host, or you can't.

Also, it's not quite sure *why* you'd want that. Your "standing back" device would experience buffer overflows/dropped data, and that can't be what you want.

If your USB bandwidth isn't sufficient to carry the two combined data streams, you'll have to use two USB2 links, no way around that, really.

Comment: Thanks! I want it this way because my main device (USB-2637) is a DAQ board and it sends and receives data continuously. This data is important, and the data volume is quite high as well. I have to make sure that there is no dropped communication between this main device and my host computer. If the other device (USB-1024LS) experiences loss of data that is not as critical and hence I am trying to figure out how to implement this configuration on a single USB 2.0.

Comment: @Chaitanya then the right solution is to reserve enough bandwidth for your main device. USB does that, it's called isochronous transfer mode, and you need to do exactly nothing with your hub to enable that, the driver of your main device does it by itself (or it doesn't, in which case, that's the only thing to fix.) Also, still highly doubtful you're really solving a real problem here. The data rate of both your devices seem to be pretty constant, so either they "fit", or they don't.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that's a great help. If possible, can you please point me towards any resource where I can learn to check if my device is reserving enough bandwidth or not?

Comment: ask the driver?

Comment: I have no idea which driver and where is it installed. I am using C functions provided by the device manufacturers to communicate with the devices. But I think I figured it out, the maximum bandwidth the device can take is 16 megabits/sec and USB 2.0 has 480 megabits/sec, so I think I am safe using the two devices from a single USB hub.